# midi packet list dose not change timestamp

Tags: ios, swift, coremidi

i have this code from here([Using MIDIPacketList in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26494434/using-midipacketlist-in-swift)) but i can't pm the user or comment on that question, so i will ask my question.
@ephemer dude if you see my question, i love your code on midi list and it work so well, but when i change the time stamp, nothing happens, it must create some delay but it will be the same as 0 time stamp.
do anyone know how to fix this?

and how i can have the time stamp out of this extension to have that in midi event, i want to be able to change time stamp for every midi event, 
to have it here:

```
 var packets = MIDIPacketList(midiEvents: [[0x90, 60, 100]])

 public typealias MidiEvent = [UInt8]

 extension MIDIPacketList {

    init(midiEvents: [MidiEvent]) {

    let timestamp = MIDITimeStamp(0) // do it now
    let totalBytesInAllEvents = midiEvents.reduce(0) { total, event in
        return total + event.count
    }

    // Without this, we'd run out of space for the last few MidiEvents
    let listSize = MemoryLayout<MIDIPacketList>.size + totalBytesInAllEvents

    // CoreMIDI supports up to 65536 bytes, but in practical tests it seems
    // certain devices accept much less than that at a time. Unless you're
    // turning on / off ALL notes at once, 256 bytes should be plenty.
    assert(totalBytesInAllEvents < 256,
           "The packet list was too long! Split your data into multiple lists.")

    // Allocate space for a certain number of bytes
    let byteBuffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: listSize)

    // Use that space for our MIDIPacketList
    self = byteBuffer.withMemoryRebound(to: MIDIPacketList.self, capacity: 1) { packetList -> MIDIPacketList in
        var packet = MIDIPacketListInit(packetList)
        midiEvents.forEach { event in
            packet = MIDIPacketListAdd(packetList, listSize, packet, timestamp, event.count, event)
        }

        return packetList.pointee
    }

    byteBuffer.deallocate() // release the manually managed memory
 }
}

 // to send use this

 var packets = MIDIPacketList(midiEvents: [[0x90, 60, 100]])

 MIDISend(clientOutputPort, destination, &packetList)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

*set the timestamp to :*

```
var delay = 0.2

var timestamp: MIDITimeStamp = mach_absolute_time() + MIDITimeStamp(delay * 1_000_000_000)
```

the delay is the time you want the midi message age to have delay.

Answer (score 0):

i figure it out, how it should work, but not quite right.
according to apple documentation, it must use mach_absolute_time() .
so i used that but i don't know how to work properly with mach_absolute_time().if anyone knows please tell me too.
if i use  var timestamp = mach_absolute_time()+1000000000 it will delay like 1 min or so.if i change the 1000000000 with any number lower than this ,will not make a delay.
do anyone know how to work with mach_absolute_time()?
i saw some code on mach_absolute_time() but they use that as timer, it is acutely a timer that give time from the fist boot ,but how to give a time as a mach_absolute_time() to work with midi timestamp.